# Mathematical Symbol

Tags: turing-machines

I remember about 10+ years ago there was a mathematical symbol used to represent population sustainability.

It resembled a downward or upward angled arrow but in dot form...if remember it was represented in a 4x4 grid but maybe have been larger.  It is the result of population seed eventuality, with no additional variances introduced into the initial population.  The result was an infinite sustainable population model that was based on reproduction and death of neighbor's

Any help refreshing my aged memory, would be most welcomed.

Had to pick a tag, so please correct the tags if not representative to the question.

Comment: Sounds more appropriate to [math.se].

Comment: When i saw it back then, it was related to a problem (at the time) with implementing the model in present day CSE...shortly after, Python and other Analysis languages that could handle the repeated calculation came on to the scene.

Comment: here is an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton the gliders are what the symbol represents